# Identity Server 4: Override behavior to generate own tokens/code when using external IdP

Tags: identityserver4

I have a scenario where we use Identity Provider 4 as our Identity Provider but it uses an external Idp. We have our APIs that our app calls that expect this token from our Identity Server 4. At the same time, we have API's of an external party that expects tokens issued by the external IdP we use (they use the same external IdP).

I have read that Identity Server 4 generates it's own token/auth code after "unpacking" what it gets from the external Idp. This will work fine when the app calls our APIs but won't (or will it?) work when we pass that token (generated by Identity Server 4) to the external APIs as it's expecting tokens from the external IdP.

Is there a way for me to override Identity Server's behavior so it doesn't generate it's own token/auth code but just uses whatever it gets from the external IdP?

In other words, some sort of a passthrough behavior?